# Is there a way to restructure fileName.module.css code to SCSS/SASS?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Only recently got started on web development. Our app is getting larger and larger and I am slowly getting overwhelmed by all the module.css files (we have 100s at this point) that we use to style every react js file separately.

Now that I am getting a lot more proficient with the MERN stack, I am wondering if there is any "smart" way of restructuring the styles to SCSS/SASS considering the current layout and size of the application. Basically, would it be wise at this point to even consider implementing scss/sass or should we just stick to it at this point?

Hope that makes sense!
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what "smart" means but sass can be very helpful. You can extract common pieces of styles with `mixin`s and and  `extends`. Use functions to be more consistency etc. I would suggest to explore some other methods such as css-in-js, styled-components etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.